# No se ejecuta correctamente un comando en Shell Script

Tags: regex, bash, shell-script

Dentro de *prueba.txt* tengo esto:

```
96 ./Downloads//sffsf
```

e intento recuperar solamente

```
./Downloads
```

a través de este código

```
ruta2=$(cat prueba.txt | grep -E "\.\/(\w*\/+)*")
echo $ruta2
```

Pero lo único que consigue imprimir por pantalla es esto:

```
96 ./Downloads//sffsf
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para que solo imprima **./Downloads**?

Cabe la posibilidad que en ese fichero haya tambien una ruta mas larga como por ejemplo

```
234 ./Downloads/Carpeta//qwerty
```

Comment: Sólo quieres que te extraiga el nombre "./Downloads"? o desde el nombre hasta donde estén los dos slashes "//"?

Comment: Cualquiera de las dos opciones me valdría.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que te extraiga desde el punto hasta las dos diagonales, tu regex está bien, pero necesitas el parametro "-o" de `grep`:

```
$ grep -Eo '\.\/(\w+\/+)*' << __eof
96 ./Downloads//sffsf
234 ./Downloads/Carpeta//qwerty
__eof
```

Y obtendremos:

```
./Downloads//
./Downloads/Carpeta//
```

Si lo que quieres es la ruta pero sin las diagonales, puedes probar con esta regex:

```
$  grep -Po '.*?\s\K.*(?=\/\/)' << __eof
96 ./Downloads//sffsf
234 ./Downloads/Carpeta//qwerty
__eof
```

Y devolverá:

```
./Downloads
./Downloads/Carpeta
```

[Aquí puedes ver](https://regex101.com/r/DFTG6Y/1) la explicación detallada de esa regex

El parametro "-o" de `grep`, le indica al programa que imprima sólo lo que encuentre que corresponda a la regex.

Sin esa opción, mostrará todo.

### Update

Esta es la salida:

```bash
ruta="$(grep -Po '.*?\s\K.*(?=\/\/)' /tmp/prueba.txt)"
echo $ruta
./Downloads
./Downloads/Carpeta
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, pero ahora al poner esto: **ruta2=$(cat prueba.txt | grep -Eo `\.\/(\w*\/+)*`)** me sale este error: **./midu.sh ./Downloads/
./midu.sh: command substitution: line 31: syntax error near unexpected token `\w*\/+'
./midu.sh: command substitution: line 31: `\.\/(\w*\/+)*'**

Comment: Me parece que pudiste haber escrito mal tu comando. Enciérralo entre comillas, y evita usar `cat`. Mejor abrelo diréctamente con `grep`, osea: `ruta="$(grep -Po '.*?\s\K.*(?=\/\/)' prueba.txt)"`

Comment: Me ayudó, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Usando [awk](https://www.um.es/innova/OCW/informatica-para-universitarios/ipu_docs/la_shell/awk.pdf) lo podrías hacer así:

```
cat prueba.txt | awk -F"//" '{ print $1 }' | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

donde:

- `cat prueba.txt`: Imprime a la salida el archivo prueba
- `awk -F"//" '{ print $1 }'`: Separa la cadena pasada por el **cat** en partes delimitadas por `//` gracias a su parámetro `-F` que establece dicho delimitador, y donde después solo imprimimos la primera de ellas mediante `'{ print $1 }'` dando como resultado esto:

```
96 ./Downloads
234 ./Downloads/Carpeta
```

- `awk '{ print $2 }'`: Sabiendo lo anterior, ahora queremos eliminar los números, que si nos fijamos estan **separados por un espacio** con la segunda cadena, por lo tanto, en este caso no usamos `-F` porque *el delimitador de espacio es el esperado por omisión en el `awk`*, pero sí le decimos que tan **solo queremos la segunda parte** mediante `'{ print $2 }'`, dando como resultado:

```
./Downloads
./Downloads/Carpeta
```